# Send E-Mail through Trigger.io app

Tags: html, trigger.io, forge

How can I implement e-mail addresses in a Trigger.io app to (externally) open the Mail application for sending an e-mail?

The basic  attribute seems not work out of the box and I didn't find anything in the official Trigger.io docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just using plain HTML works fine for my Trigger.io app:

```
<a href="mailto:your-email@address.com">Contact me</a>
```

You can even add a predefined subject, just add `?subject=email-subject` at the end of the `href` attribute. Check out the [mailto syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto) for more examples.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks :-) I just didn't test this on the device, because it doesn't work in the simulator for obvious reasons.

Comment: Oh, you're absolutely right! I should've mentioned that it won't work on the simulator..

Comment: Is there a way to embed html in the email body? regular mailto syntax (on browsers) doesn't allow that.